# UIScrollView: Content first appears too low

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Before posting a lot of code I want to ensure it's not a commonly known issue (independent of the specific code) so first I'll explain my problem in general:

In the storyboard I created a UIViewController, added a UIScrollView as well as another UIView (hierarchical subviews). I need the scroll view to push the content up when the keyboard appears so the textfield stays visible. When running the app everything works fine besides the fact, that the content appears closer to the bottom of the screen than defined in my storyboard. As soon as I tapped the textfield the content is scrolled up (by adjusting `scrollView.contentInset` and `scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets` to `(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)`) and its position is like expected. When pressing the return key, the keyboard disappears, the content scrolls down again (by adjusting `scrollView.contentInset` and `scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets` to `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`) but now everything is like I want it to be and like it was defined in the storyboard.

Trying to understand what's happening I also let print out to the console some of the y points in `viewDidLoad()`, `keyboardDidShow` and `keyBoardDidHide` but when comparing those, they're all the same. What did I miss out? Do you need to see some specific part of my code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `scrollView.contentInset and scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets to (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes I did but initial position remains the same @Putz1103

Comment: Oh, it works when putting it into `viewDidAppear()`! What do you think, is this an elegant solution or just a workaround for something missing within the code? What does it actually affect and why is it set differently when the view loads first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as desired when setting up

```
viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}
```

Any comments concerning other/better solutions are welcome!

Comment: Don't forget to call `super`.

Comment: @Kamchatka I'm rather new to programming: What could happen when missing to call super? Is it always needed?

Comment: If you override a method without calling super, you *override* the behavior defined in the parent class. Adding a call to super makes sure you still keep whatever behavior was defined there.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue - I messed around with all the solutions above, finally found the fix.

For me, I just had to flip the right switch in the ViewController constructor:

```
public ViewController ()
{
    AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
}
```

I'm suspecting the results would be similar for LoadView(), ViewWillAppear(), etc...

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that:

- `edgesForExtendedLayout` contains the upper edge
- `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is set on your view
  controller?

Comment: Can you explain where I should set these and how exactly? To which layout is `edgesForExtendedLayout` related to? `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` is meant to be set in the `viewDidLoad()`? I don't know whether it's a acceptable solution but as replied in the comments of my initial post, another workaround quite of solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work even better, without visibly "bumping" the first item on the view, but doing so before it is shown to the user:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```